# SAS - duplicate excel file in another folder

Tags: excel, sas

If i have an Excel "Covid19_report &todaysdate. &time..xlsx" file  in a folder called F:\A

and I want to put this exact file into folder F:\B but duplicated 6 times like this:

"1_Covid19_report &todaysdate. &time..xlsx"

"2_Covid19_report &todaysdate. &time..xlsx"

"3_Covid19_report &todaysdate. &time..xlsx"

"4_Covid19_report &todaysdate. &time..xlsx"

"5_Covid19_report &todaysdate. &time..xlsx"

"6_Covid19_report &todaysdate. &time..xlsx"

is there a macro to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to use SAS to do this, and not use operating system commands, powershell, etc.?

Comment: FYI if you're working on a server and the F drive isn't connected to the server you'll have issues doing this :(

Answer (score 1):

The SAS function `FCOPY` will be helpful.

Copying binary files requires a fileref be created with options such as `RECFM=N` and `LRECL=<filesize>`

Example:

Create a sample Excel file and copy it 6 times to target files having an index prefix in their filenames.

```
* Create sample Excel file for copying;

ods noresults;
ods excel file='c:\temp\prices.xlsx';
proc print data=sashelp.stocks;
run;
ods excel close;
ods results;

* Copy a source file 6 times to a target file with an index number prefix name pattern;

data _null_;
  length source_ref target_ref $8;

  * determine name part from full pathname;

  source_file = 'c:\temp\prices.xlsx';
  source_name = scan(source_file,-1,'\');

  * determine source file size for efficient options;
  * NOTE: FCOPY only works on files < 1G in size;

  rc = filename(source_ref, source_file);
  fid = fopen(source_ref);
  bytes = finfo(fid,'File size (bytes)');
  fid = fclose(fid);
  rc = filename(source_ref);

  options = 'recfm=n lrecl='||trim(bytes);

  * prepare SOURCE fileref;

  source_ref = '';
  rc = filename(source_ref, source_file, 'DISK', options);

  * duplicate in same folder (via transtrn);

  do index = 1 to 6;

    * compute target file name and corresponding full path;

    target_name = cats(index,"_",source_name);
    target_file = transtrn(source_file, trim(source_name), target_name);

    * create temporary TARGETR fileref (due to ref value passed in being blank);
    target_ref = '';
    if 0 = filename (target_ref, target_file, 'DISK', options) then do;
      rc = fcopy ('source', target_ref);
      rc = filename(target_ref);  * clear TARGET fileref;
    end;
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks - please my answer below

Answer (score 0):

i tried doing this, but do not work:

```
%let todaysDate = %sysfunc(today(), yymmdd10.); %put &todaysDate;

data _null_; ftime = intnx('hour',time(),0,'b'); cftime = 
compress(put(ftime,hhmm.),":"); call symputx("ftime",cftime); run;

%put &=ftime.;


%let path = F:\A; 
%let file = COVID-19 Report &todaysdate. &ftime.;

filename source "&path.\&file.";

data _null_;   length target_ref $8;

  do index = 1 to 6;
    target_file = cats("&path.",index,"_&file.");
    target_ref = '';

    * create temporary fileref (due to initial ref value being blank);
    if 0 = filename (target_ref, target_file) then do;
      rc = fcopy ('source', target_ref);
      rc = filename(target_ref);
    end;   end;   stop; run;
```

Comment: To copy an XLSX file using FCOPY() you probably need to add settings to let SAS know to treat the file as BINARY and not TEXT.  Try adding RECFM=F and LRECL=512 to your FILENAME definitions.